# Default text in TextView

Tags: android, textview

If I have a `textview` like this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Elapsed Time: " />
```

I want my app to always display "Elapsed Time: ", followed by some value which I will update in my MainActivity. How can I do this without doing

```
mTimeTextView.setText("Elapsed Time: " + <some value here>);
```

each time?

Comment: is update settext you did every second with handler?

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this is to use tokens in a string resource.

in strings.xml

```
<string name="elapsed_time">Elapsed time: %1$s</string>
```

in layout xml

```
<TextView android:text="@string/elapsed_time"
```

in code

```
mTimeTextView.setText(resources.getString(R.string.elapsed_time, <some value here>))
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a string resource in res/values/strings.xml

   ```
   <string name="time_prefix">"Elapsed Time: %s"</string>
   ```
2. Get the resource string and concatenate your value with it

   ```
   String text = getResources.getString(R.string.time_prefix);
   String formattedText = String.format(text, X);
   ```
3. Set the formatted text to textView

   ```
   mTimeTextView.setText(formattedText);
   ```

Note: if your value, X, is an integer then use `%d`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot unless you place two textviews together with no margin between them. The textview on the left will have the "Elapsed Time: " text and the textview on the right will have some value. Then, you only update the textview on the right.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried creating a custom TextView and overriding setText..?
I'm not by my computer at the moment but will try it and send some code.